# cublasSdot is working slower than cublasSgemm

Tags: c++, cuda, cublas

In my toy example I first multiply matrices of size `32x32`,  `100 000` times, and after that I calculate scalar products of two vectors of size `1024`, `100 000` times again. For the first I used `cublasSgemm`, for the second - `cublasSdot`.

As a result, time for first calculation is `530 msec`, for the second - `10 000 msec`. However, in order to multiply matrices we need to perform `32^3` operations (multiply-add), and for scalar product just `1024=32^2` operations.

So why am I getting such result? Here is the code:

```
__device__ float res;
void randomInit(float *data, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        data[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
}
int main(){
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    float out;
    cudaError_t cudaerr;
    cudaEvent_t start1, stop1,start2,stop2;
    cublasStatus_t stat;
    int size = 32;
    int num = 100000;

    float *h_A = new float[size*size];
    float *h_B = new float[size*size];
    float *h_C = new float[size*size];
    float *d_A, *d_B, *d_C;
    const float alpha = 1.0f;
    const float beta = 0.0f;
    randomInit(h_A, size*size);
    randomInit(h_B, size*size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, size *size *sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, size *size * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, size *size * sizeof(float));
    stat = cublasCreate(&handle);
    cudaEventCreate(&start1);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop1);
    cudaEventCreate(&start2);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop2);
    cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, size, size, size, &alpha, d_A, size, 
                d_B, size, &beta, d_C, size);
    cudaEventRecord(start1, NULL);
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size *size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size *size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, size, size, size, &alpha, d_A, 
                        size, d_B, size, &beta, d_C, size);
    }
    cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, size*size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaEventRecord(stop1, NULL);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop1);
    float msecTotal1 = 0.0f;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&msecTotal1, start1, stop1);
    std::cout <<"total time for MAtMul:" << msecTotal1 << "\n";
    cudaEventRecord(start2, NULL);
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size *size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size *size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        cublasSdot(handle, 1024, d_A , 1, d_B , 1, &res);
    }
    cudaEventRecord(stop2, NULL);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop2);
    float msecTotal2 = 0.0f;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&msecTotal2, start2, stop2);
    std::cout << "total time for dotVec:" << msecTotal2 << "\n";
    cublasDestroy(handle);
    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);
    delete[] h_A;
    delete[] h_B;
    delete[] h_C;
    return 1;
}
```

Update: I tried also to perform dot product with `cublasSgemm` by treating vector as `1 by 1024` matrix. The result is `3550 msec`, which is better, but still 7 times more then in the first calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that you're not handling the pointer mode correctly for the call to `cublasSdot`.

You'll want to read [this section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#scalar-parameters) of the manual.

Furthermore this:

```
    cublasSdot(handle, 1024, d_A , 1, d_B , 1, &res);
                                               ^^^^
```

is illegal under any circumstances.  It is not legal in CUDA to take the address of a device variable in host code.  You can certainly do it, but the results are garbage.

When I modify your code as follows:

```
cublasSetPointerMode(handle, CUBLAS_POINTER_MODE_DEVICE);
float *dres;
cudaMalloc(&dres, sizeof(float));
cudaEventRecord(start2, NULL);
cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size *size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size *size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    if(cublasSdot(handle, 1024, d_A , 1, d_B , 1, dres) != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) {std::cout << ".";}
}
```

I get about a 2:1 ratio of execution time for `cublasSdot` to `cublasSgemm` which may be plausible, particularly for these sizes.  Under the hood, the dot operation implies a parallel reduction.  1024 threads can compute the partial results, but then a 1024-thread-wide parallel reduction is required.  The gemm does not need a parallel reduction, and so may be quicker.  1024 threads can be assigned to produce the 1024 results each in a single thread.  For a memory-bound algorithm, the difference between 32^2 and 32^3 operations may not be that significant, but the parallel reduction implies significant additional operations.  When I then change `size` in your program from 32 to 128, I see the ratio reverse, and the matrix multiply does indeed become 3x longer than the dot product.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But after I implemented your code, I get ratio 10:1, which is just 2 times better than what I had. And still, why multiplying 1x1024 matrices (which is dot product)  is much longer then 32x32 matrices (see update)? You told, that cublasSgemm doesn't use reduction algorithm.

Comment: Increase the `size` as I suggested.  You seem to think everything works linearly down to zero.  But 100,000 loops adding up to 500ms means each call is on the order of 5us.  This is in the ballpark of kernel launch overhead.  So you're not measuring what you think you're measuring, which is why the results are hard to explain based on operations.